# Random float how many numbers?

Tags: netlogo

Netlogo =

I wonder how many numbers are potentially there when you use random-float 100? How many it can select in that interval. Is it like 99999999999999999? So the probability is 1/99999999999999999 to be selected?

Comment: NetLogo uses 64-bit floating point numbers, per [the Math section in the programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.1.0-RC1/docs/programming.html#math).  "The range of integers is +/-9007199254740992 (2^53, about 9 quadrillion)."  But a 64-bit float represents not just integers, but decimal values as well, so there are even more than the 9 quadrillion possibilities.  You can learn more about 64-bit floating point [at the wikipedia doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Thank you. So that means that the probability to draw two times the same number is low?

Comment: Yes, it's extremely unlikely to get the same random number twice.